# MongoDB/Express: Why does Array.includes return false instead of true?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm working on an tiny app that allows user to participate in polls, but I'm having problems checking if the current user has already voted in the poll. Everything else works fine, save for the IIFE that checks for said condition, as seen in the code snippet included. Indeed, I'm getting `false` as opposed to `true` with the data I have i.e. I already seeded the DB with sample data, including a random poll that contains the array of IDs for users who've already voted. I tried testing one ID against said array, which returns false as opposed to the expected true. What gives?

Below are the relevant snippets.

**Model**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ChoiceSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  votes: { type: Number }
});

const PollSchema = new Schema({
  title: { type: String },
  category: { type: String },
  choices: [ChoiceSchema],
  addedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  votedBy: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }]
});

const Poll = mongoose.model('Poll', PollSchema);

export default Poll;
```

**Controllers**

```
import Poll from '../models/poll';

export default {
  fetchAllPolls: async (req, res) => {
    /*...*/
  },

  fetchSpecificPoll: async (req, res) => {
    /*...*/
  },

  voteInPoll: async (req, res) => {
    const { category, pollId } = req.params;
    const { name, choiceId, voterId } = req.body;

    try {
      const poll = await Poll.findById(pollId);
      const choice = await poll.choices.id(choiceId);

      const votedChoice = {
        name,
        votes: choice.votes + 1,
      };

      // Check if user has already voted in poll
      const hasVoted = ((votersIds, id) => votersIds.includes(id))(
        poll.votedBy,
        voterId
      );

      if (!voterId) {
        res
          .status(400)
          .json({ message: 'Sorry, you must be logged in to vote' });
      } else if (voterId && hasVoted) {
        res.status(400).json({ message: 'Sorry, you can only vote once' });
      } else {
        await choice.set(votedChoice);
        await poll.votedBy.push(voterId);
        poll.save();

        res.status(200).json({
          message: 'Thank you for voting. Find other polls at: ',
          poll,
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(404).json({ error: error.message });
    }
  },

  createNewPoll: async (req, res) => {
    /*...*/
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to compare ObjectId with String representing the mongo id.

This should work:

```js
const hasVoted = ((votersIds, id) => votersIds.findIndex((item) => item.toString() === id) !== -1)(
  poll.votedBy,
  voterId
);
```

or

```js
const hasVoted = ((votersIds, id) => votersIds.findIndex((item) => item.equals(new ObjectId(id))) !== -1)(
  poll.votedBy,
  voterId
);
```

---

**EDIT:**

As @JasonCust suggested, a simpler form should be:

```js
const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some(voter => voter.equals(voterId));
```

Comment: A note on using `equals`: it can take a string or an objectId as an argument so there is no need to cast it. Also, there really is no need for an IIFE here.

Answer (score 1):

It is more than likely that `poll.votedBy` is not an array of ID strings. If you are using it as a reference field then it is an array of BSON objects which would fail using [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) because it uses the [*sameValueZero*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness) algorithm to compare values. If that is true then you could either convert all of the IDs to strings first or you could use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and the [`equals`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#equals) methods to find a match.

#### Update: showing actual code example

Also, [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) would provide an easier method for returning a boolean value.

```js
const hasVoted = poll.votedBy.some((voter) => voter.equals(voterId));
```

Comment: Exactly right. I followed the other guy's suggestion and got it to work.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando Glad to hear it. I included an example of a simpler approach as there really is no need for an IIFE.

Comment: Perfect! I'll go with this approach for obvious reasons. I appreciate the help.